# character array of bitstring

Tags: c, char

```
for(i = 0; bitstr[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(!(bitstr[i]=='0' || bitstr[i]=='1')){
        printf("Not a valid bitstring!");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        sum = sum*2+bitstr[i];
    }
}
printf("%d", sum);
```

When I enter 101 for instance, it prints 339, when it should print 5 as the answer. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `'1'` and `'0'` are characters `'1'` and `'0'`, not integer values. You need to subtract `'0'` from them to obtain numeric values:

```
sum = sum*2+(bitstr[i]-'0');
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @dasblinkenlight is correct in that one needs to subtract a `'0'` within the loop.

Strong suspect **another issue**.

The "101" entered does not detail which digits are most significant as "101" and its reverse are the same.  Nor does it show *how* `bitstr[]` was entered.

The *usual* assumption is that the left most digit is most significant and that the data was entered with the Most Significant digits first.  So a change of indexing is also needed.

```
char bitstr[100];
int sum = 0;
scanf("%s", bitstr);
size_t i,l;
l = strlen(bitstr); // add
for(i = 0; bitstr[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(!(bitstr[l-1-i]=='0' || bitstr[l-1-i]=='1')){
        printf("Not a valid bitstring!");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        sum = sum*2+ (bitstr[l-1-i] - '0'); // change index and subtract '0'
    }
}
printf("%d", sum);
```

---

Recommend to re-order the `for()` loop from `strlen(bitstr) - 1` to `0` and simplify the index calculation.  Left "as is" to match OP.